# Fragment not added after configuration change

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I am trying to recreate view after screen rotation, 
her I added "TestFragment" to an activity, screen get rotated onConfigurationChange() is called, here I do setcontextview() so that view is recreated and trying to replace existing "TestFragment" with same instance.
but fragment is not added, can I know anything wrong in this code.

```
public class TestFragmentActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("Test", "onCreate");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
        createFragment();
    }

    private void createFragment(){
        Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("TestFragment");
        if (fragment == null) {
            Log.d("Test", "not found");
            fragment = new TestFragment();

        }else {
            Log.d("Test", "found");
        }
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
        fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame1, fragment, "TestFragment");
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
        getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
    }


    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        Log.d("Test", "onConfigurationChanged");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
        createFragment();
    }
}

    public class TestFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_fragment, null, false);
        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.d("Test", "onDestroy TestFragment");
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Comment: In Android, Activity will be recreated by default during orientation change. So views will be recreated. No handling needed for that. Isn't it happening?  Why do you handle it when you are expecting the default behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your manifest

```
<activity
        android:name=".TestFragmentActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation">   
</activity>
```

Comment: I have already added  android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" this onConfigChange is getting called, issue is with fragment not getting added

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to call onConfigurationChanged() method if you define android:configChanges="orientation" in Manifest file because Activity will auto manage the current state and content on orientation change.